# raspap, DHCP, and routing traffic through static eth0

Tags: raspbian-buster

I flashed the latest Raspian image, setup Raspap, and made the following modifications:

wlan0
IP: 10.0.11.1
Subnet: 255.255.254.0

eth0
IP: 10.0.11.2
Subnet: 255.255.254.0

DHCP is enabled and giving out IPs in the 10.0.11.100-200 range.

The main thing I want to be able to do is have clients able to access a device with a static IP connected to eth0 at 10.0.10.12. I thought that by specifying the 255.255.254.0 subnet the 10.0.10.x range would also be accessible, but it is not. When the device is plugged into eth0, a client connected to the AP cannot access either the AP or the device. When the device is unplugged, a client **can** access the AP.

For debugging, I have had the eth0 wired to my home network and am finding that clients of the AP are being served by the home router's DHCP, which seems quite strange, but I assume the iptables configuration as-is is passing those requests through even though the Raspi has a DHCP server as well.

Why does plugging in a device to eth0 make both the AP and the device inaccessible, and why is DHCP getting handled upstream? Is it iptables-related?

Comment: What is the actual question? is it about the DHCP issue? Did you want to know how to stop the AP clients getting DHCP from the router?

Comment: Edited to hopefully make a bit clearer.

Comment: It seems that you have a standalone access point, not connected with an uplink to your internet router, and only one device connected to **eth0**. What netmask has the device with ip address 10.0.10.12? Why can't you use ip address 10.0.10.1/24 (netmask 255.255.255.0) on **eth0**?

Comment: The device with IP 10.0.10.12 has netmask 255.255.255.0. There's nothing stopping me from using 10.0.10.1/24, it originally had 10.0.10.5/24 and I decided to try a broader subnet because that had the same behavior. Is your suggestion that I try that approach?

Comment: I moved eth0 and wlan0 to 10.0.10.3/24 and 10.0.10.250/24 respectively, and hooked up the device with IP 10.0.10.12/24 to eth0. From the raspi I am able to communicate with the device. From a client on the AP I cannot communicate with any of the above IPs. If I unplug eth0, I am able to communicate with 10.0.10.250/24.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know **RaspAP** and what it is doing with your network, but here some general considerations about your setup.

As you noted you have two DHCP server running on one broadcast domain (means subnet). This is out of specification and any question about its behavior is meaningless. You can't say anything which DHCP server dynamically wins to serve an ip address and which DHCP server registered it in its address pool. So the first step is to avoid two DHCP server on one subnet.

Then you cannot just give different subnet masks to different devices on a network. I prefer to use bit masks instead of subnet masks. They are both the same to define the subnet part on an ip address. You have to plan your network and have to split it into subnets. All devices belonging to one subnet should have the same bitmask. Otherwise you may have overlapping of different subnets, means one ip address belongs to two subnets on different devices. This is out of specification and cannot work and it seems that is the case in your setup. If you know what you are doing it is possible to have different bit masks on different devices but a smaller subnet must exactly fit into the bigger subnet with its boundaries. But this is mainly used on router and sophisticated networking. I cannot give a tutorial about this. You may have a look at [Wikipedia - Subnetwork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork).

Now to your problem. Very common is to use a bitmask of `/24`, for example 10.0.10.12/24. It masked just the last byte of the 4 byte ip4 address (netmask 255.255.255.0). That's easier to understand. Using an [IP Calculator](http://jodies.de/ipcalc) you will find that this ip address belongs to:

```
with netmask 255.255.255.0 = bitmask /24
ip address 10.0.10.12/24 belongs to subnet 10.0.10.0/24 with address range 10.0.10.1 to 10.0.10.255
ip address 10.0.11.12/24 belongs to subnet 10.0.11.0/24 with address range 10.0.11.1 to 10.0.11.255

with netmask 255.255.254.0 = bitmask /23
ip address 10.0.10.12/23 belongs to subnet 10.0.10.0/23 with address range 10.0.10.1 to 10.0.11.255
```

There are some more details shown with the IP calculator. With this example you can see that bitmask `/23` is overlapping with two subnets using bitmask `/24`. If you don't respect this it will confuse the routing on your devices. To have subneting as simple as possible you should only use bitmask `/24` on all devices.

because **eth0** and **wlan0** on the RasPi have ip addresses you do not use a bridge. So you have to configure routing between two **different** subnets, for example:

```
ip address eth0  = 10.0.10.1/24 with subnet 10.0.10.0/24, address range 10.0.10.1 to 10.0.10.255
ip address wlan0 = 10.0.11.1/24 with subnet 10.0.11.0/24, address range 10.0.11.1 to 10.0.11.255
```

Subnets are different here, no overlapping. If you want bigger subnets you can use:

```
ip address eth0  = 10.0.10.1/23 with subnet 10.0.10.0/23, address range 10.0.10.1 to 10.0.11.255
ip address wlan0 = 10.0.12.1/23 with subnet 10.0.12.0/23, address range 10.0.12.1 to 10.0.13.255
```

The devices connected to an interface must have an ip address of its range. This isn't the case with your setup.

Comment: I will first try moving everything back into the smaller, original subnet; this was my first approach but as I recall it was not working. I am a little confused at the bottom of your message. Are you saying that the two interfaces must be in different subnets? I will try this if the simple approach doesn't work.

Comment: @NickSpacek Routing means: routing between different subnets. That's by definition. So each interface **must** be on a different subnet. If you want to merge interfaces into one subnet, you have to use a bridge.

Comment: Ah, that's a basic concept I was missing. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: Yup, down to a networking newbie making some basic errors. Working now with eth0 and wlan0 in separate subnets.